# mysqlの初期設定でunknown variable 'tmpdir=/tmp'が出て進めない

Tags: mysql

[こちら](http://tukaikta.blog135.fc2.com/blog-entry-197.html)のサイトなどを参考にmysqlのインストールを進めたところ

```
% mysql_install_db --verbose -user='whoami' --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
mysql_install_db: [ERROR] unknown variable 'tmpdir=/tmp'
2016-02-08 16:57:42 [ERROR]   Unrecognized options
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。

アンインストールして再度試してみましたが同じエラーが出ました。
原因がわかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最近のバージョンでは、mysql_install_db の `--tmpdir` オプションは廃止されているようです。特にこだわりが無ければ、指定せず実行して良いかと思います。(`mysql_install_db` は `mysqld` のラッパーですので、指定したい場合には `mysqld` コマンドを直接叩くことになるでしょう。)

本題から外れますが、`whoami` をシングルクオート「'」ではなくバッククオート「`」で括らないと意図した通りに動かないはずです。これは `whoami` の実行結果 (現在のログイン名) に置換するためです。